# Install specific version of PHP in Alpine Linux

Tags: php, linux, alpine-linux

I am trying to install PHP v8.0.2 on an Alpine Linux, but I get the following message:

```sh
apk add php8=8.0.2
fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.13/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.13/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
ERROR: unable to select packages:
  php8-8.0.6-r0:
    breaks: world[php8=8.0.2]
```

Is there any way I can get it to install?
If I just do `apk add php8` it adds version `8.0.6`, but there is an issue on that version that breaks my site.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 3):

It is impossible via apk, as the Alpine Linux team are not keeping "older versions" in their current repositories (as stated [here (gitlab.alpinelinux.org)](https://gitlab.alpinelinux.org/alpine/abuild/-/issues/9996) and [here (stschindler.medium.com)](https://stschindler.medium.com/the-problem-with-docker-and-alpines-package-pinning-18346593e891))

So you have to go the way Richard Wan proposed and build it from source, if you can't make your site running with php 8.0.6 or 7.4.19.

Answer (score 1):

The [PHP official Dockerhub](https://hub.docker.com/_/php) page has version tags for official PHP versions in various flavors.

For the PHP 8.0.2 Alpine image, you could use `php:8.0.2-alpine3.12` as your base image, instead of `alpine:3.13`.

For other PHP 8.0.2 Alpine 3.12 based images, see:
https://hub.docker.com/_/php?tab=tags&page=1&ordering=last_updated&name=8.0.2

Comment: i came here trying to build a custom image since none of the standart ones seem to have both php 8.1.12 and rsync ... this answere did provide zero help

Comment: @clockw0rk Just install the `rsync` package on the php 8.1.12 image. You're welcome.

Comment: i made a custom image for dockerhub since i could not sudo into the existing ones to install packages. lesson learned from this is better cook your own soup. and learn cooking lol

Answer (score 0):

maybe u can install php from source, since it's hard to find a specific version of php and install that using apt-get or yum install. And here is the source code of php 8.0.2:
[source code of php 8.0.2](https://www.php.net/distributions/php-8.0.2.tar.gz)

And the following article will give u some instructions of how to do that.It is php 7 installation, but the method is kinda same. Here is the articlel:
https://blacksaildivision.com/php-install-from-source

Answer (score 0):

You can also build from source

```bash
sudo apk update
sudo apk add --no-cache gcc g++ make cmake pkgconf sqlite-dev

wget https://www.php.net/distributions/php-8.2.0.tar.gz --directory-prefix "$HOME"
tar -xvf /opt/php-8.2.0.tar.gz --directory "$HOME"
cd "$HOME/php-8.2.0" || exit

sudo ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/php \
  --with-openssl \
  --with-curl \
  --with-zlib \
  --with-mysqli \
  --with-pdo-mysql \
  --enable-cli \
  --enable-fpm \
  --enable-xml \
  --enable-mbstring

sudo make
sudo make install
```

Please check what flags you need in the documentation.